# Implement divided differences in C++ with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to implement in C++ the divided differences formula as it appears [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DividedDifference.html).

So far I have come with this

```
template<typename F, typename T>
T divdiff(F f, T t1, T t2) {
  return (f(t1) - f(t2)) / (t1 - t2);
};

template<typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
T divdiff(F f, T tstart, Args... t, T tend) {

  return (divdiff(f, tstart, t...) - divdiff(f, t..., tend))/ (tstart - tend);

};
```

It compiles fine but when it try to use it for example like this

```
 double r = divdiff([](double x) { return 2 * x; }, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

I got the following error

```
note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 4 were provided
T divdiff(F f, T tstart, Args... t, T tend) {``
```

My compilers is gcc

> Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr
>   --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0 Thread model:
>   posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Does anyone knows why it does not work and how to fix it

Comment: it seems that the variadic argument must be at the end in order to make it work

Comment: That's right, The variadic argument must be the last one. You can pack it in a tuple,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> template<typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
> T divdiff(F f, T tstart, Args... t, T tend)
> ```

Since `Args... t` is not at the end of the parameter list, it will not be deduced. Such deduction is not allowed partly to simplify the language rules, and partly to help keep programs simple (and prevent shooting oneself in the foot.) You could specify `Args ...` explicitly like `divdiff<F, double, double>`, but then for the recursive call it would be difficult to remove the last `double`.

In any case, the variadic template approach suffers template bloat, and inefficiency as the argument list may be copied by each function call. Since the elements of the sequence should all be the same type, consider using iterators instead. Then you can add a convenience overload using `std::initializer_list` for array-based iterable sequences.

```
template< typename F, typename bidirectional_iterator >
typename std::iterator_traits< bidirectional_iterator >::value_type
divdiff( F f, bidirectional_iterator first, bidirectional_iterator last ) {
    bidirectional_iterator next = std::next( first );
    bidirectional_iterator prev = std::prev( last );
    auto diff = next == prev?
        f( * first ) - f( * prev )
      : divdiff( f, first, prev ) - divdiff( f, next, last );
    return diff / ( * first - * prev );
}

template< typename F, typename T >
T divdiff( F f, std::initializer_list< T > il )
    { return divdiff( f, il.begin(), il.end() ); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/703c131b090e7bbf).

Comment: Thats pretty cool actually, but I have to call my function like ```divdiff(f,{a,b})```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using variadic templates?

Comment: @krvajal Requiring the braces may be a feature, not a bug — it indicates that there's a list there. You could add a wrapper function to add braces, and that would use a variadic template. Sure, it's possible to use variadic templates all the way down, but it would be more obfuscated, less efficient, and less flexible — so why?

Comment: because your solution is  recursive and I am for one where the recursion is expanded at compile time, not at runtime. So again why it will be less efficient?

Comment: @krvajal It's unknown that recursion will be expanded in either solution. The decision is up to the inliner, which usually limits total function size. Inefficiency occurs when a call isn't inlined; then the argument list needs to be copied at O(N) cost. By the way, this isn't a particularly efficient algorithm. If performance is important, consider dynamic programming or some other way to reuse intermediate results.

Comment: (To clarify: despite `initializer_list` storing its size at runtime, the compiler may be able to treat its size as a compile-time constant.)

Comment: @krvajal By the way, here's the disassembly of [Christopher's solution](https://godbolt.org/g/GS4zak) vs. [mine](https://godbolt.org/g/UCfjeh) for a sequence of eleven `double`s. You can see that inlining is still pretty aggressive under ordinary recursion, and you can see the long sequences of `mov` instructions that appear in the template-recursive case when inlining fails.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the standard, tuple-unpacking recursive solution.
I changed your lambda, because linear functions are kinda boring here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

// The base version of divdiff, ends recursion
template<typename F, typename T>
T divdiff(F f, T t0, T t1) {
    return (f(t0) - f(t1)) / (t0 - t1);
}

// This divdiff overload takes a tuple and an index sequence
// The index sequence specifies which elements from the tuple will
// be unpacked as arguments for a divdiff call
template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto divdiff(F f, T arg_tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return divdiff(f, std::get<Is>(arg_tuple)...);
}

template<typename F, typename T, typename ...Ts>
T divdiff(F f, T t0, Ts ...right_args) {
    // pack all arguments into a tuple
    auto arg_tuple = std::make_tuple(t0, right_args...);
    // make an index sequence whose size is one less than the
    // current recursion's argument count
    using next_index_sequence = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>;
    // get the value of the final argument in tn
    auto tn = std::get<sizeof...(Ts)>(arg_tuple);
    // Call divdiff, first using the tuple/sequence overload for the left
    // side arguments.
    // Then call it with the easily-obtained right side arguments.
    return (divdiff(f, arg_tuple, next_index_sequence{})
        - divdiff(f, right_args...)) / (t0 - tn);
}

int main() {
    double r = divdiff([](double x) { return x * x * x; }, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    std::cout << r << '\n';
}
```